# Does supervisord kill running processes on with the restart command?

Tags: linux, supervisord

We have supervisord running in production and I'd like to know if after running `$ supervisorctl restart group-name:*` if running processes are killed immediately or if supervisor lets running processes finish.

Tried my best to find that out in the docs and the source code.

Comment: I don't know this program specifically, but normally init-like programs send `SIGTERM` first so the program has a chance to exit gracefully, then `SIGKILL` a few seconds later if they got stuck.

Comment: If you're worried about open network connections, it's possible to pass them over a socket and get them back in the new process, but I'm not aware of anyone other than systemd that supports this. But why not use systemd?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, supervisorctl will kill process, because usually under supervisor work worker script which never stops, hence it is no way to supervisorctl understand when script is ready to be stopped.